# Google App Engine blocking access to my backend services

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

In Google App Engine, I have 3 services, 1 for front end, 2 for back end.

Is there a way to block http calls to my backend services for accounts not from my company's domain (and the service account of the front end), but allow everyone http access to my front end service?

I know there is the firewall option, but this is restricted to IP addresses, I would prefer user based

If it matters all services are python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no option to filter traffic to specific App Engine services within a single application/project:

- [App Engine Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/creating-firewalls) filters by source IP ranges but can only be set for the whole app, not per service.
- [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview) can filter access by user account as you'd prefer but also applies to the whole app. Also, it only supports user account and can't be used with service accounts.

One option you may have would be to split your app in 2 different projects. Keep the front-end in one project open to the world and restrict access to the backend services in your other project via firewall rules.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Identity-Aware Proxy, but couldn't create access to the site at all, do you know which permissions need to be set to allow viewing of the site?

Comment: You can add a user named "allUsers" and give him "IAP-secured Web App User". This should give access to everybody to your front-end

Comment: So just to update, if anyone would care, my problem was that in my app.yaml handlers, I had the `login` set on some handlers - this does NOT play well with IAP

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the following being used in `task queues` in GAE. Maybe it would help.

If u were using python 2, in standard environment, i think u could have used login handler element in `app.yaml` file.
You could have added following lines to your app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: worker.app
  login: admin
```

This prevents other users from accessing this service.

But the same login handler is not available for python3, according to Google Docs.

Just found following in Google Docs:

```
If a task performs sensitive operations (such as modifying data), you might want to secure the handler URL to prevent a malicious external user from calling it directly. You can prevent users from accessing task URLs by restricting access to App Engine administrators. Task requests themselves are issued by App Engine and can always target a restricted URL.

You can restrict a URL by adding the login: admin element to the handler configuration in your app.yaml file.
```

You can also call your backend services through `cloud tasks` or `task queues` (both are almost the same i guess), in case this only work for cloud tasks.

Find the code usage here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/taskqueue/counter

Find details about handler here.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element

Find details about Cloud task and queue here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers